# ¿Qué significa "la tercera edad"?

Tags: expresiones

Una amiga me dijo:

> Estoy a cargo de mamá que es una señora de la tercera edad.

¿Qué significa "la tercera edad"?

Comment: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tercera_edad

Comment: Vale aclarar que tambien se usa mucho el termino 'Jovenes de la Tercera Edad' para referirse a las personas ancianas

Comment: The literal translation is "the elderly". _I'm taking care of my mother that is an elderly woman_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Tercera edad" es sinónimo de "ancianidad". Es un eufemismo a menudo usado en la prensa y que se ha vuelto parte de la cultura popular.

Hay una entrada en el DLE en la definición de [*edad*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EN8xffh):

> [**tercera edad**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EN8xffh)
>
> 1. f. Período avanzado de la vida de las personas en el que normalmente disminuye la vida laboral activa.
> 2. f. Conjunto de personas que están en la tercera edad.

---

"Tercera edad" is a synonym of old age. Take a look to the definition of [*edad*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EN8xffh).
This is an euphemism that press tends to use. Nowadays, it became part of folk popular culture.

Comment: No solo la prensa, si no en general en la sociedad, los centros de ancianos se llaman "centros de la tercera edad".

Comment: y también : U3E | Centro de Estudios Universitarios para la Tercera Edad. (1a edad = juventud, 2a = adultez, 3a = vejez)

Comment: El termino de ancianidad no es preciso. Ya que la ancianidad comprende tanto la tercera edad como la cuarta edad, o sea la senectud.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: La RAE discrepa contigo; mira el enlace que proporciono en la respuesta. ¿Tienes alguna evidencia para respaldar lo que dices?

Comment: Los diccionarios son eso, diccionarios, la práctica es la que dicta el criterio de la verdad y lo cierto es que un anciano puede estar en la cuarta edad. La tercera edad yo tengo entendido que son los que han dejado la madurez temprana (la adultez) y aún sigen siendo útiles para labores en la sociedad.

Comment: @CesarGon en muchos conceptos la RAE va mucho por detras de la sociedad. Y este concepto es mas social que de lenguaje. Si miro por ejemplo la definición de la RAE que aportas veo atisbos de leer algo fuera de época, y de ver incluso los ancianos como lo desechable. Será mi sensibilidad pero definir anciano como última etapa de la vida, seguramente es verdad pero, esta fuera de epoca. Enmarcar los ancianos sólo como carne de cementerio o camino al cementerio me hace que quiera pensar todo lo contrario que la RAE en ese aspecto.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: Tus elucubraciones me parecen muy bien. Pero el diccionario de la RAE no habla de que los ancianos sean desechables ni los califica como carne de cementerio. Si no tienes evidencias para apoyar tus argumentos, lo más honesto es que los retires dignamente. Espero que lo entiendas.

Comment: La RAE en cuanto a ese concepto y a otros muchos esta fuera de tiempo. Busca cuarta edad en el diccionario RAE y no lo encontrarás. Y sin embargo hay estudios muy serios que ya definen una cuarta edad. La cual incluye a los ancianos. y lo del cemneterio está muy evidente en lo que dice etapa final de la vida. Ya pudieran siendo ellos todos unos viejitos en mejorar esa definición. En conceptos sociales, cientificos y hasta incluso en conceptos hasta de la lengua la real academia esta muy pobre e imprecisa y aveces hasta equivocada.

Comment: buscar un concepto de actulidad social en ese diccionario es como buscar ciencia en la biblia.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero, el término _cuarta edad_ no es utilizado en el lenguaje común. A fin de cuentas _tercera edad_ implica que dividimos la vida en tres partes, sin emitir juicios de valor. Los autores de tus estudios quizá la dividan en cuatro seguramente con buenos motivos, vale, pero Al OP le hablan de _persona de la tercera edad_ y dudo que oiga nunca _de la primera edad_ o de la segunda o de la cuarta, a no ser que lea los estudios que mencionas.

Answer (score 1):

La niñez es la primera edad. Un adulto es de la segunda edad. Y una vieja es de la tercera edad, es decir en la segunda niñez.

Comment: Sólo que nadie habla de _primera edad_ o de _segunda edad_.

Comment: @DeStrangis: Es la verdad, pero son los antecendentes logicos de la "tercera edad."

Comment: Añado: Nadie habla de la primera o segunda edad porque no es necesario. *niño* y *adulto* son conceptos neutros e incluso positivos. *viejo* es un sustantivo con connotaciones despectivas, y *anciano*, aunque más suave, también tiene connotaciones negativas. *la tercera edad* pues es un eufemismo y se usa como tal.

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia se viene utilizando tanto por entidades públicas como privadas la expresión **adulto mayor** en reemplazo de **tercera edad**, para referirse a las personas mayores de 60 años.

Por el ejemplo el Ministerio de Salud tiene el documento [Adulto mayor vida y dignidad](https://www.minsalud.gov.co/Paginas/Adulto-mayor-vida-y-dignidad.aspx)