# ¿Quiénes son las "personas de la tercera edad"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Who are "persons of the third age"?

Yo veo y leo esto en CNN en español:

> *"...un centro para personas de la tercera edad"*

Is "the third age" the final stage of life? Such as: personas de la primera edad son niños, personas de la segunda edad son desde 20-65 o semejante, y personas de la tercera edad son ancianos, a lo mejor?

Comment: Para traducciones en contexto [Linguee](http://www.linguee.es/) es un buen recurso. La traducción que ofrece para [tercera edad](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/search?source=auto&query=tercera+edad) en la mayoría de contextos es *the elderly*. Dado que *tercera edad* es un eufemismo para evitar decir "viejos" o "ancianos", la *primera* y la *segunda edad* no existen porque "niños", "jóvenes" y "adultos" no son palabras tabú.

Comment: Very similar (if not a duplicate): [¿Qué significa “la tercera edad”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3073/12637)

Comment: Marked as duplicate to [¿Qué significa “la tercera edad”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3073/1674) after this discussion in Meta: [¿Deberían considerarse como duplicadas preguntas iguales formuladas en diferentes idiomas?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2524/1674).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a polite way of saying old people, and generally refers to those who are retired. Here's what the DRAE says:

> **edad**. [...] **tercera edad**. **1.** *f.* Período avanzado de la vida de las personas en el que normalmente disminuye la vida laboral activa. **2.** *f.* Conjunto de personas que están en la tercera edad.

Answer (score 1):

As said, it's the polite way to refer to *long-lived* people. They are considered to be in the *third age* when they reach the 60+ years old.

Third age people are not necessarily considered as retired ones. Many ones at that point of age have many disabilities, for example.

In my country we often call a person *third age* right away we see them walking with a crutch, but we don't refer to them as *old man/woman,* we politely do it by saying *a third age person.*

Answer (score 1):

In many countries where many British live, including for example the UK and in my case, Spain, there exist organisations called "U3A". "U3A" is an abbreviation of **University of the third age** and are organisations for (mainly) retired people. Only the requirement to speak English is mandatory. The "U3A" organisations are social groups in which many activities can be enjoyed; for instance, Play bridge, Play tennis, Creative writing, photography group, sailing group etc

Comment: What, no Tiddlywinks?!?